# Purpose of '*' in front of Python3 function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, iterable, iterable-unpacking

I saw the code for a ResNet CNN in Python3 and PyTorch [here](https://d2l.ai/chapter_convolutional-modern/resnet.html) as follows:

```
def resnet_block(input_channels, num_channels, num_residuals,
                 first_block=False):
    blk = []
    for i in range(num_residuals):
        if i == 0 and not first_block:
            blk.append(Residual(input_channels, num_channels,
                                use_1x1conv=True, strides=2))
        else:
            blk.append(Residual(num_channels, num_channels))
    return blk
```

To add the modules, the following code is used-

```
b2 = nn.Sequential(*resnet_block(64, 64, 2, first_block=True))
b3 = nn.Sequential(*resnet_block(64, 128, 2))
b4 = nn.Sequential(*resnet_block(128, 256, 2))
b5 = nn.Sequential(*resnet_block(256, 512, 2))
```

What does "*resnet_block()" mean/do?

Comment: It "unpack" list/tuple to positional arguments. It converts `[1,2,3]` to (1,2,3...). You can use it in any position. Also there is `**` operator - the same but for keyword arguments. Look this - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/packing-and-unpacking-arguments-in-python/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the star operator mean, in a function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/what-does-the-star-operator-mean-in-a-function-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically `*iterable` is used to unpack the items of an iterable object as positional arguments. In your question `resnet_block` returns a list, and the items of that list are passed to `nn.Sequential` rather than the list itself.

Comment: The iterable unpacking is not restricted only to positional arguments; It can be used in all scenarios: positional-only arguments, keword-only arguments, a combination of positional & keyword arguments.